# Accepting Invitations Through Android CalendarContract

Tags: android, calendar

I am working on a project which involves reading in and manipulating data with the Android calendar APIs. I will be doing this both with the API 14 CalendarContract, and the more dubious undocumented APIs for older devices, for some backwards compatibility.

I am currently playing around with the databases, to get a feel for how they work. So far so good.

One issue I have found is that when I am trying to change the status of an attendee's status (that of the user, not of any of the other attendees), this does not seem to be actually accepting an invitiation to that event.

For example, with 2 google calendar accounts I do this:
Account A is logged in on device
Account B creates event and invites Account A
Event shows up on Account A device
Attempt to accept the invitation via the Calendar APIs.

It is that last step I am struggling with.

This is the kind of thing I am doing:

```
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

event.put("attendeeStatus", "1");//accept

Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase() + "attendees");
Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, id);

iNumRowsUpdated = getContentResolver().update(eventUri, event, null, null);
```

This successfully updates the attendeeStatus to 1 in the database.

This does not, however, update their actual attendance. So my question is, is there another field in the database schema that is used for this purpose? Or is there a better/more efficient solution? And/Or is it possible to force this to then sync back with the Google Calendar system so as I can see that Account A has accepted on Account B's Google Calendar account?

Worth noting that I have tried the below:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(eventUri, null);

getContentResolver().notifyChange(eventsUri, null);
```

Which has not helped.

Note: The above code is specifically for the pre-4.0 devices, but is near enough the same for ICS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved:

The above works with Google Calendar accounts, but does not sync correctly over Exchange connections.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you could possibly shed some light on my issue.  I have created a calendar SyncAdapter for 2.3.3 and 4.0.  So users will have create accounts on their devices for my apps and calendars/events will be associated to their account (not a Google account).  When creating an event with invites, after saving it, a message says "Invitations will be sent.", but nothing is ever sent.  Is there anyway for my app to send these e-mails? I know it works for Google accounts.